# How can I fix rattling tremolo?

Tags: electric-guitar, tremolo-system

Why can a tremolo make a rattling sound? I changed the strings to thicker ones. I thought that the problem was a raised tremolo (but it didn’t visually look like it), tried to tighten the screws on it and it didn’t help. What else can I check myself or is it better go to a specialist?

Comment: You might think it's the tremolo, but it could be something else. Even a bad volume pot can make a rattling sound (heard only electronically), due to microphonic effects.

Answer (score 1):

Take the bar off - does it stop?

Most common cause is the actual whammy bar rattling in its thread.
Fix is a few turns of PTFE tape on the thread before you screw it in, available from any hardware/plumbing store. Don't use sticky tape of any kind. PTFE is "teflon" & won't stick or jam.

If that's not it, you're going to have to give us better information.

Comment: Never worked out why the wangy bar is such an awful fit. Mainly in the Fender style guitar. One of the not-so-good points on Strats. Mostly he did a great job, which still holds good after 60 yrs, so can't complain. Except about that fit.

Comment: Agree - but I'm the son of a plumber, so I learned the PTFE tape trick waaay back in the 70s ;-)

Comment: I see it's been mentioned before & not just by me - https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=ptfe

Comment: @tim on ebay you can buy a small spring that keeps the bar on a strat from rattling.

Comment: @bigbadmouse - I use them. 5mm or 6mm. But some Stratalikes have a through hole rather than a blind one. Won't work on those.

Comment: Spring £1 - might work on some guitars. PTFE tape, 20p - fits anything, so much left on the roll you can give it to your dad to fix the pipes or keep it for a lifetime's supply for you & all your friends ;)